# Python: How to validate an IP Address with a CIDR notation (import socket)

Tags: python, validation, sockets

I've got a script which is using argparse to pull flags from the command line and using socket to validate an IP Address. So far it works if I'm just using the standard IPv4 X.X.X.X format. What I want to do is validate an IP Address that includes a CIDR notation. How can I modify my bit of code to validate the 2-digit integer in the CIDR field (ie: 192.168.2.1/32)

```
import argparse
import socket

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-i", "--ipaddr")
args = parser.parse_args()

# Validate IP Address Given in (-i) argparse
try:
        s = socket.inet_aton(args.ipaddr)
except socket.error:
        print ""
        print("Bad IP Address entered")
        print ""
        sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Python 3

There is an [ipaddress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) module that may do the job.

The constructor of the class `Ip4Network` handles both `255.255.255.255` and `255.255.255.255/32` (and also IPv6 format, with `Ip6Network`)

So you may add in your code

```
import ipaddress
```

and create an `Ip4Network` with the code:

```
try:
    ip_addr = ipaddress.ip_network(args.ipaddr)
except ValueError:
    # handle bad ip
```

Than, continue with your code on the socket:

```
socket.inet_aton(str(ip_addr))
```

you have only to convert it in a string.

#### Python 2.7

The `ipaddress` must be installed from the repository (`py2-ipaddress`) and has some issue between `str` and `bytearray` interpretation of string (refer [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2-ipaddress#changes-from-py2-ipaddress-2-0-1-and-earlier))

So it works in my experiments if you do:

```
ipaddress.ip_address(bytearray('192.168.1.1'))
ipaddress.ip_network(u'10.0.0.0/24')
```

#### Additional remarks

##### CIDR

To complete the aswer considering also the comment made by @Dave:

- `ipaddress.ip_network` validates against ip address, not CIDR notation.
- `ipaddress.ip_network` validates against networks, not CIDR notation.
- To validate a CIDR notation **with host bits set** you must set the `strict` input parameter to `False` to avoid raise a `ValueError('%s has host bits set' % self)`.

  ```
  ipaddress.ip_network('192.168.1.1/24', False)
  # IPv4Network('192.168.1.0/24')
  ```

Comment: I tried this suggestion and it just errors out for both 192.168.2.1 and 192.168.2.1/32. Does having Python 2.7.5 make a difference with import ipaddress?

Comment: with `ipaddress.ip_address` you get a `ValueError` when passing a cidr address i think it should be `ip_addr = ipaddress.ip_network(args.ipaddr)`

Comment: @balder is right. Current documentation clarifies that ipaddress.ip_address must be used with addresses (no /xx at the end of the string, e.g., 192.168.1.1) while ipaddress.ip_network must be used with network addresses, or loosely speaking ranges of addresses (that ends with /xx, e.g., 192.168.1.0/24). The post has been corrected.

Comment: @MatteoRagni @balder, this is not valid. Neither ip_address or ip_network will validate the notation {ipaddress in a subnet}/{CIDR block}. `ip_addr = ipaddress.ip_network(192.168.1.1/24)` will return a value error if you include host bits. `ip_network` requires you to provide the network address, it wont accept an address inside of the network. I see no way this can be done with ipaddress. So `ip_addr = ipaddress.ip_network(192.168.1.0/24)` will work, but any address inside of the subnet will not. This is documented as an example (https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/ipaddress.html)

Comment: @Dave the answer has been modified to address (pun intended :D) your comment.

Comment: I just noticed that there is an actual answer by @Dave about my last comment, so let's together have a look at it and click upvote!

Answer (score 1):

Turn off strict mode and use `ip_network`

```
ipaddress.ip_network('192.168.1.10/24',False)
IPv4Network('192.168.1.10/24')
```